# Selenium WebDriver element traverse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to know how to find the specific element text. i have page as below

```
<div id="a">
   <div class="first"><span class="fclass">firstdiv</span></div>
   <div class="second"><span class="sclass">seconddiv</span></div>
</div>
```

How to get locate *second div* text here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java. Of course this would not work if the element is hidden. See api doc [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("sclass")); 
String text = element.getText();
```

*With css*

```
By bycss = By.cssSelector(".second>span.sclass");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(bycss); 
String text = element.getText();
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response. is that second is built-in api or my my class name

Comment: Sorry. Corrected. That was a typo on my side. Apologize